# Nested graphviz trees?

Tags: graphviz

TL;DR: Is there some short-notation in graphviz for creating trees, that doesn't require re-typing the node names?

I am trying to create a mindmap with graphviz's `twopi` tool. In order to avoid rewriting the same labels over and over (or using obscure shorthands), I was trying to use nested braces.

Essentially I expected the two subgraphs here to have the same structure:

```
digraph example {            
        subgraph AA {     
                root -> {a b c}
                a -> {a1 a2 a3}
                b -> {b1 b2 b3}
                c -> {c1 c2 c3}
        }
        subgraph XX {
                _root -> {
                        _a -> { _a1 _a2 _a3 }
                        _b -> { _b1 _b2 _b3 }
                        _c -> { _c1 _c2 _c3 }
                }
        }
}
```

but instead, the first one has the hierachical structure I wanted, while the second has unintended connections from the root node. Compiled with `twopi -Tpng example.dot -o example.png`:

[image]

The first form is fine with such short symbolic names, but when the labels contain actual text, the text file quickly becomes hard to read.

The second form would help, but obviously I understood the effect of grouping in graphviz.

Is there some syntax, that would allow to avoid repeating node names as I tried in `subgraph XX`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there isn't. From https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html:

> An edge statement allows a subgraph on both the left and right sides of the edge operator. When this occurs, an edge is created from every node on the left to every node on the right.

This means that you have to repeat *something* in order not to have edges from a branch (including the root) in the tree to *everything* on that branch. I usually resort to repeat the nodes that are easiest to write.

I don't think this will make you much happier, but here's an approach where only the root node is repeated:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.2/viz.js" type="javascript/worker"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@2.4.2/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

var dotSrc = `
digraph example {            
    subgraph AA {     
        root -> {a b c}
        a -> {a1 a2 a3}
        b -> {b1 b2 b3}
        c -> {c1 c2 c3}
    }
    subgraph XX {
        _root -> _a -> { _a1 _a2 _a3 }
        _root -> _b -> { _b1 _b2 _b3 }
        _root -> _c -> { _c1 _c2 _c3 }
    }
}
`;

d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
  .engine("twopi")
  .renderDot(dotSrc);

</script>
```